# Como ver o espaço em disco que o index ocupa no banco de dados?

Tags: sql, postgresql, índices

Tenho a tabela **manutencao** com a coluna **id_produto (varchar(MAX))**, porem a mesma não é a chave primaria, a tabela tem 900 mil registros então resolvi criar indices para otimizar as buscas.

Fiz os seguintes testes:

```
create index manutencao_id_produto_idx on manutencao using hash(id_produto);
drop index manutencao_id_produto_idx

CREATE INDEX manutencao_id_produto_idx on manutencao (DECODE(MD5(id_produto), 'HEX'));
drop index manutencao_id_produto_idx

create index manutencao_id_produto_idx on manutencao (id_produto);
drop index manutencao_id_produto_idx
```

A performance foi semelhante em todos eles, quero saber quanto de espaço em disco cada um ocupa, estou acessando o banco com o `datastudio`, se tiver uma query para pegar este valor melhor ainda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei algo:

```
SELECT c2.relname, c2.relpages
FROM pg_class c, pg_class c2, pg_index i
WHERE c.relname = 'manutencao' AND
      c.oid = i.indrelid AND
      c2.oid = i.indexrelid AND
      c2.relname = 'manutencao_id_produto_idx';
```

Segundo esta página http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/disk-usage.html, cada **c2.relpages** tem cerca de **8 kilobytes**, então:

```
SELECT c2.relname, (c2.relpages * 8)||' kilobytes'
FROM pg_class c, pg_class c2, pg_index i
WHERE c.relname = 'manutencao' AND
      c.oid = i.indrelid AND
      c2.oid = i.indexrelid AND
      c2.relname = 'manutencao_id_produto_idx';
```